# JavaFX Shape CSS Properties

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-css

I´d like to know how to implement the properties of Shape Class as described in [Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape)?

Example:

I have a custom checkbox css:

```
.check-box-money .box {
    -fx-border-color: #d8d8d8;
    -fx-border-width: 4;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: -color-primary;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-shape: "M21.1,21.1h-21l5.6-21h21L21.1,21.1z M1.4,20.1h19l5.1-19h-19L1.4,20.1z";
}
```

But the line of the shape is too thin, so I´d like to change.

So I tried to implement `-fx-stroke-width` but nothing worked.

Comment: **a)** what value have you tried to assign to `-fx-stroke-width`? It should be an integer or percent. If integer, it will result in number of pixels - this is not directly related to JavaFX, but to [stroke-width](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeWidthProperty); **b)** Could you provide an **mcve**?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu JavaFX CSS != CSS, I still used the `css` tag because a lot of other JavaFX questions use it. However I used integer to test it and nothing worked.